# Add user in Docker container, UID mismatch when running Jenkins job

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a Jenkins pipeline in a Docker container. The Docker container creates an unpriviliged user to run as:

```
RUN useradd jenkins --shell /bin/bash --create-home
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/src && chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins
USER jenkins
WORKDIR /home/jenkins/src
```

Jenkins runs this as:

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 [-v and -e flags etc.]
```

This works when I run Jenkins manually as my personal account (uid 1000) on the host. But now I changed it so that Jenkins is started automatically by systemd, and using a specifiy `jenkins` user with uid 1006, gid 1009:

```
docker run -t -d -u 1006:1009 [-v and -e flags etc.]
```

This mismatch causes my build to fail. I also get all kinds of problems, like this prompt in the container:

```
I have no name!@6d3b27a803e4:/$
```

Creating a jenkins user in the container seems like something that there should be a recipe for. **How do I get the UIDs on host and container to match?** What is the best practice?

- Add something like `usermod --uid $HOST_UID jenkins` to the Dockerfile?
- There seems to be no way to tell Docker to map host uid 1006 to container uid 1000, is there?

Comment: Do you need the `-u` option at all, what's the requirement for the host and container uid to match? Is the `-v` used for named or host volumes?

Comment: The shell prompt is totally cosmetic; since the main thing your container is doing probably isn't running an interactive shell, it doesn't really matter that the uid isn't in the container's `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: @BMitch The `-u` parameter is passed by Jenkins, and it is hardcoded. --
@DavidMaze I know, it is just a symptom. The real problem is that the container must access files on the host, that have a certain uid, but I don't know that uid at build time. -- 
I think I solved it in the meanwhile with an ENTRYPOINT script that sets up the user. When I find time I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem when run Jenkins job and found the solution working for me.
As you wrote above if you run job in container Jenkins automatically starts Docker like this:

```
docker run -t -d -u 113:117 [-v and -e flags etc.]
```

He takes his UID and GID locally and uses in Docker run command. But when steps commands start executing in the container docker doesn't have this values inside. It's cause of this trouble:

```
I have no name!@6d3b27a803e4:/$
```

The solution for me was to mount "passwd" and "group" files inside container like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'your_image' 
            args '-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -v /etc/group:/etc/group'
        }
    }
    
    stages {        
        stage('stage_name') {                
            steps {                
                sh '''
                    some_commands
                '''
            }
        }
    }
```

And create user in Dockerfile like this:

```
RUN groupadd jenkins && useradd -m -d /var/lib/jenkins -g jenkins -G root jenkins
```

Hope this helps someone)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
docker {
  image 'your_image'
  args '-e HOME=/tmp/home'
}
```

/tmp is writable for everyone. No need to create user.

Comment: This solved the problem elegantly. Other answers required integration / planning with jenkins master.